How is causality in Laplace transform related to Fourier transform?

Taking the Laplace transform of a system given by a differential equation yields its transfer function $H(s)$. The region of convergence of the causal impulse response of the system lies right of the most right pole in the complex plane. Suppose the system is stable. Then the region of convergence will include the imaginary axis. We know that the imaginary axis corresponds to the Fourier transform of the impulse response $h(t)$ of $H(s)$. Does this imply that the Fourier transform will also yield a causal $h(t)$?

In my book it says we can continue the Laplace transform analytically  in the complex plane such that the whole Laplace plane is included in the region of convergence except for the poles. This would imply that I can take the Fourier transform of unstable systems by substituting $s=j\omega$ . How does that even make sense? Im so confused! And how is that related to the impulse response being causal then?



If we are given a function $H(s)$ and we're told that it is a Laplace transform, then there are usually many possible corresponding time-domain functions. Let's assume that $H(s)$ is rational (so we can talk about poles), then the possible regions of convergence (ROCs) are limited by the real parts of the poles. If the ROC is to the right of the rightmost pole, the corresponding time-domain function is right-sided, if the ROC is to the left of the leftmost pole, the time-domain function is left-sided, and if the ROC is between two poles, we have a two-sided time-domain function.
Let's now assume that there are no poles on the imaginary axis. If we set $s=j\omega$ we obtain a valid Fourier transform $H(j\omega)$. Its inverse Fourier transform equals the time domain function corresponding to the (unique) ROC of $H(s)$ which includes the imaginary axis.
Example:
$$H(s)=\frac{2a}{a^2-s^2}=\frac{1}{s+a}-\frac{1}{s-a},\qquad a>0\tag{1}$$
Depending on the ROC, $H(s)$ is the Laplace transform of the following three time-domain functions:
\begin{align*}
h_1(t) &= \left[e^{-at}-e^{at}\right]u(t),& \textrm{Re}(s)>a \\
h_2(t) &= \left[e^{at}-e^{-at}\right]u(-t),& \textrm{Re}(s)<-a \\
h_3(t) &= e^{-at}u(t)+e^{at}u(-t)=e^{-a|t|},& -a<\textrm{Re}(s)<a
\end{align*}
The inverse Fourier transform of
$$H(j\omega)=\frac{2a}{a^2+\omega^2}\tag{2}$$
is given by $h_3(t)$, which corresponds to the only stable impulse response, i.e., to the ROC which includes the imaginary axis. The functions $h_1(t)$ and $h_2(t)$ don't have a Fourier transform.
Analytic continuation of $H(s)$ to all points of the complex plane except for the poles does not affect any of the above, and it is not related to the Fourier transform.

Thanks for this great answer. This made things very clear for me now. One thing that is still unclear: What is the point of analytically continuing the complex plane?
Also: Question 1) would be answered with YES.

I can answer this myself now! The reason why we do this is for control engineering purposes. When for instance designing a stable closed loop system for an unstable plant, the nyquist criterion can be used to design a compensator. Here, we do indeed look at H(s=jw) but as you have pointed out: This has nothing to do with the fourier transform.
